# How can I solve this problem of required fields in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, null, laravel-5.7

When I submit the button then it's showing (name and email) is required. I have tried many times but I can't solve this problem.

```
    class ContactController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * @param Request $request
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
         * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
         */
        public function sendMessage(Request $request) {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required',
                'subject' => 'required',
                'message' => 'required'
            ]);

            $contact = new Contact();
            $contact->name = $request->name;
            $contact->email = $request->email;
            $contact->subject = $request->subject;
            $contact->message = $request->message;
            $contact->save();

            Toastr::success('Your message successfully send.', 'Success', ["positionClass" => "toast-top-right"]);
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
```

Up method:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('subject');
            $table->text('message');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<form class="contact-form" method="post" action="{{ route('contact.send') }}">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input  name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="  Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="  Email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input name="subject" type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="  Subject">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <textarea name="message" type="text" class="form-control" id="message" rows="7" placeholder="  Message"></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-send">Send </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: What are you trying to do? What happens instead?

Comment: Post code, not images. Add a description of your problem, we're not mind readers.

Comment: Please read this post again and help me. Thanks

Comment: paste here your request data

Answer (score 0):

Could you check in your Laravel debug toolbar in request payload, if values of name and email are being passed?

Comment: it's solved, brother. I just changed username to user_name. username is the common name for laravel and when we use this name then we faced some problem like that. so, thanks for commenting.